# Azure Form Recognizer returns status 403 forbidden - x-ms-forbidden-ip

Tags: azure-form-recognizer, azure-ai

Since yesterday I have been getting a header error message: "x-ms-forbidden-ip" when trying to analyze a document in Power Automate. I am using the Analyze Document for Prebuilt or Custom models (v3.0 API) action.

The action was working previously.

I have tried recreating the connection and have checked the Azure firewall settings of which there are none. The Form Recognizer service is set to "All Networks".